# Creating master build file

Tags: java, ant

I want to create an integrated ant build file for my project.
My project has 5 subprojects. Now I've to call "jar" and "war" targets of these subprojects. How do I call these targets in the integrated build file?

Comment: I would suggest using the subant task: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[ant]%20subant

Comment: this has already been done it is called Maven ( modules )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, if the following is what you want, but you can call different ant files from within a single (in your case your master-) ant file:

```
<target name="buildAll">
  <ant antfile="path/build-file1.xml"/>
  <ant antfile="path/build-file2.xml"/>
  <ant antfile="path/build-file3.xml"/>
</target>
```

See: [Ant Manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/) especially this chapter: [Ant Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) for more information